# How to find out a certain color value the current colorscheme is using for certain stuff?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin, statusline

I need this in order to finish a plugin I'm making in order to change the colors of the statusline depending on the mode.

However I've run across an obvious problem, how would I know what theme the user is using? And even if I knew I can't make specific colors for each theme.

So, how to know the foreground and background colors that the current theme is using for the statusline for example.

EDIT 1:

In case I wasn't clear, I'm looking for a way to find out the `ctermfg`/`bg` and `guifg`/`bg` for certain stuff. Right now the statusline. :)

EDIT 2:

Apparently if I do `:hi StatusLine` I get what I need, however I need to refine it to get only the value, and not all of it. Guess I'll have to use some regex to find out the value. If anybody knows an easier way please share it (or if you already figured it out with the regex). Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the `synIDattr()` function to query the various attributes (like foreground and background color) of syntax highlighting. To determine the ID of the highlight group, `hlID()` can be used. See `:help hlID()`:

```
:echo synIDattr(synIDtrans(hlID('StatusLine')), 'fg')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the background with

```
:echo &background
```

according to `:help background` there should be a `foreground` setting, too, but it doesn't work for me.

**Edit:**
There are the variables `guibg`, `guifg`, `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` in `:hi[glight]`

Comment: Oh no, I don't mean the option to use either a dark/light background. But rather a way to know what color the theme was using. For example how to know the exact color the theme is using for comments for example.

Comment: Oh I read the documentation you pointed to and I think that might be it, however I'm not sure.

Comment: It might be possible using the `&fg` and `&bg`, however I need to run some tests to make sure. If you find out definitely be sure to tell me about it. :)

Comment: Hmm nope, seems that isn't it. Never the less a +1. :)

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `ctermbg` and `ctermfg` in `:hi`

Comment: Yes that's right! I'm gonna edit the question. Also for `guifg` and `guibg` as well (I can't remember if it's called exactly that).

Comment: it is, just found it and wanted to add :)

Comment: I did find something, I put it in my main post.